# error en mysqli_fetch_array PHP

Tags: php, input, base-de-datos

tengo este codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>registro</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="correo" required>
<input type="password" name="con" placeholder="contraseña" required>
<input type="submit" value="loggear">
</form>
</body>
```

y php

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pw2="";
$db="programate";
$email=$_POST["email"];
$pw=$_POST["con"];
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw2);
$sel=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT EMAIL,PW FROM registro WHERE EMAIL='$email'");
$sesion=mysqli_fetch_array($sel);
if ($pw == $sesion["PW"]) {
   $_SESSION["name"] =$email;
   echo "iniciado secion";
}else{
   echo "verifique si no ubo un error al escribir los datos"; 
}
?>
```

me dice que tengo un error en mysql_fetch_array(), exactamente este error:
Advertencia : mysqli_fetch_array () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, booleano dado en (ubicacion) en la línea 11

¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: Al margen del error presentado considera que usas un driver para conectarte a mysql obsoleto desde hace ya varios años, investiga sobre mysqli

Comment: ¿que alternativa puedo usar?

Comment: busca sobre mysqli o PDO en la documentación de PHP, no es una buena idea que sigas ese desarrollo construyéndolo en algo obsoleto